# Simply use variables throughout functions

Tags: python

I've been scrolling through Google for a while now and I'm yet to find an answer for this. Let's say I have:

```
def equation(a, b):
    price = (a + b) * 2
    return price


def main():
    equation(5, 10)
    print(price)
```

and I want to print `price` through `main()`, how do I do this? Whenever i run it, it says something like price is not defined

Comment: did you try returning something in your first function? look there. I believe you can figure this out! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Comment: Do you want to (A) transfer the _value_ of `price` from `equation` to `main`, or (B) simply make the `price` _variable_ accessible to both `equation` and `main`?

Comment: Calling a function doesn't automatically store its return value in a magically created variable. If you want to get the return value in the `price` variable, you have to assign it there: `price = equation(5, 10)`.

Comment: make `price` accessible to both

Comment: In that case, you'll need to make `price` a [global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) variable, rather than a local one. However, please note that [this is considered bad practice](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) - instead, you should try to `return` it to `main` as a local variable, as described in the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement) linked to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because although you call the function you don't save its return value anywhere. Try instead

```
def main():
    price = equation(5, 10)
    print(price)
```

Note also that the variable in the calling function doesn't need to relate to naes inside the called function (which are generally only available inside the function). So you could equally well write

```
def main():
    some_other_name = equation(5, 10)
    print(some_other_name)
```